# Extendible hashing - cmu 15-445/645

Tags: database, algorithm, hash

I'm trying to solve `Question 3 c)`, originating from here: https://15445.courses.cs.cmu.edu/fall2021/files/hw2-clean.pdf, solutions are available here: https://15445.courses.cs.cmu.edu/fall2021/files/hw2-sols.pdf (so this is no homework ...)

Link to image of question (can not embed images due to low reputation)
[Extendible hashing question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj9uv.png)

Starting from the table in the image linked above, delete keys 10,12,7,24 & 8.

The global depth seems to start at 3 as there are 3 bits used.

There are 2 questions:

1. Which deletion causes the first reduction in local depth? That's the deletion of 7, I understand that one.
2. Which deletion causes the first reduction in global depth? The answer is supposed to be "24", but for the life of me, I don't see it. My answer would be "None of the above". Can somebody shed some light on this please?

edit: I think I understand it, after deletion of 24, the global depth can decrease to 2. All indices ending with the same 2 bits point to the same bucket, so they can be merged. It was not clear to me, because that rule is not described in the assignment, I guess it's a general rule the assignment creator assumed.